# Collector.toMap using generics

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, collectors

I am having hard time using streaming API in Java for generics map. I have a map which extends LinkedHashMap in the following way

```
public class LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
  private int size;

  public LRUCache(int size) {
    super(size);
    this.size = size;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
    return size() > size;
  }

  public LRUCache<K, V> collect() {
    return entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)
    );
  }

}
```

I am experimenting with a dummy method `collect` which will actually stream on the entrySet, apply some filters on it and then return a new LRUCache, but `Collectors.toMap` keep throwing an error which says

"Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

I know this is some issue with Collectors.toMap generics definition. But, I am not able to figure out the right generics to get rid of the error and achieve the streaming and collecting functionality

Comment: It's unclear what your `collect()` method is meant to do: are you simply copying the map?

Comment: Note that the 2-args version of `toMap` returns a `Map`, not a `LRUCache`. You will need to use the 4-args version to provide a map factory..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` includes in its implementation is a no-argument constructor that acts as a *supplier to the `toMap` collect operation*. You can introduce the same as well by including:

```
public LRUCache() {
    this(10); // default size
}
```

Thereafter you can collect the `LRUCache` implementation  using the `toMap` override with `LRUCache::new` supplier in the following manner:

```
public LRUCache<K, V> collect() {
    return entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue, 
                    (a, b) -> a, LRUCache::new));
}
```

**Note:-** That what matters is providing a supplier to collect to a different implementation than a `HashMap` which is what you get using the other overloaded implementation of `toMap`.

Comment: You don't actually need the extra constructor: you could use `() -> new LRUCache(10)` instead of `LRUCache::new`.

Comment: @AndyTurner True, I guess the answer isn't clear in terms of stating the obvious that the *supplier* is the crucial part.

Answer (score 1):

You appear simply to be trying to copy your map/cache. There is no need for streams to do this.

Add a (maybe private) constructor, which invokes the map copy constructor:

```
private LRUCache(Map<K, V> map, int size) {
  super(map);
  this.size = size;
}
```

Then just use this in your collect method:

```
public LRUCache<K, V> collect() {
  return new LRUCache<>(this, size);
}
```

Or, without adding the constructor:

```
public LRUCache<K, V> collect() {    
  LRUCache<K, V> copy = new LRUCache<>(size);
  copy.putAll(this);
  return copy;
}
```

Comment: That was just an example. I plan to add some filters in between. @Naman's solution worked perfectly fine

Comment: @skjindal93 do be sure to include relevant details in the question: that would have caused me to give a different answer.

Comment: Sure. My bad. I did mention it in the question that I would be adding filters, but I agree I should have been more specific in the code snippet